# Firefox is shrinking tables inside inline-block divs. What's going on here?

Tags: html, css, firefox

I need to display a table inside an inline-block div element.

Chrome, Internet Explorer, Safari and Opera all render the table the same whether it is the child of a block div element or an inline-block div element, which is what I would expect. Example:

[image: Chrome, IE, Safari, Opera rendering]

Firefox, on the other hand, shrinks the table when the containing div's display property is inline-block. Example:

[image: Firefox rendering]

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/PvZ2d/7/

**Markup:**

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    background: red;
    width: 33%;
}

<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>More Content</td>
            <td>Even More Content</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>More Content</td>
            <td>Even More Content</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<div style="display:inline-block;">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">Content</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">More Content</td>
            <td style="white-space:nowrap;">Even More Content</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Question:** How can I work around this? Is this a bug in Firefox?

According to the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display):

> The inside of an inline-block is formatted as a block box, and the
>   element itself is formatted as an atomic inline-level box.

Given this, I don't understand why changing the display property to inline-block would alter the layout of child elements.

Comment: Are you willing to set an explicit width on the table?  [http://jsfiddle.net/PvZ2d/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/PvZ2d/8/)

Comment: @TLS No, the table width property needs to be "auto"

Comment: I believe tables by default take the space they are given by their parent, so if placed in an `inline-block` `div`, which has a dynamic, content-based width, the table in Firefox is actually doing it correctly.  If the parent of the table has dynamic width, how does the table know how wide to be?

Comment: Or it's just a bug/difference in Firefox and I really have no idea what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a shrink-wrap situation the width of the inline-block should be the preferred width of the table, which in Firefox seems to be the sum of the preferred widths of the columns; at this stage the percentage width is ignored since there is nothing for it to be a percentage of.

The non-inline block doesn't have a shrink-wrap width, so the above doesn't apply; the block is as wide as the page body and then you lay the table out inside it.  At this point the ancestor width is known, so percentage widths can be applied.

The spec doesn't specify the rendering in this situation, so it's hard to say that any particular rendering is right or wrong, unfortunately.